# What does the word connive mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I write a sentence in my history book which was:

> In this respect, as Time wrote, "the world knew that it had, in a sense too deep, too simple for the world to understand, connived at his (Gandhiji's death) as it had connived at Lincoln's."

What does the verb "connive" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

"Connive" has two related, yet distinct meanings.

The most common meaning is to *deliberately* conspire to cause something to happen, eg "*they connived to take over the business*" would mean planning or conspiring to take over a business perhaps by foul means.

The secondary meaning though is simply to *tacitly approve* of something - to *allow* something to happen without actually causing it. Interestingly this is the meaning perhaps closest to the root meaning of the word which comes from the Latin *conniver* meaning "to close eyes to".

In your example, it is clear that the entire world clearly didn't *cause* or plan for Lincoln's death. The inference then is clearly that they *turned a blind eye to*, or *ignored it*.